# Bootstrap 2 col in same height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to make both in same height without using margin-bottom: -999px?

I more refer using jquery to control height instead of use css trick. I have tried margin-bottom: -999px, it just make mess.

```
<div class="container-fluid">       
<div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">

            <div class="content-box">

                <h4>Vision</h4>

                <p>Global leader in ensuring quality learning in the Financial Services Industry.</p>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">

            <div class="content-box">

                <h4>Mission</h4>

                <p>Finance Accreditation Agency (FAA) is an international and independent quality assurance and accreditation body for the Financial Services Industry (FSI) supported by Bank Negara Malaysia and Securities Commission Malaysia (SC). It is responsible for quality assurance of learning initiatives within the FSI, including programme accreditation, institutional audits and programme evaluation.</p>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pFbXd/

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/pFbXd/2/

Comment: I don't want use fix height too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this calculate the highest div and then force the div to have the same height.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.container-fluid').each(function(){  
        var highestBox = 0;

        $(this).find('.content-box').each(function(){
            if($(this).height() > highestBox){  
                highestBox = $(this).height();  
            }
        })

        $(this).find('.content-box').height(highestBox);
    });     
});
```

Here is the Working Demo. http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/pFbXd/4/

Comment: if i add image in div, it will not in full height.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can use **[height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/)**:

```
$('.content-box').each(function() {
    $(this).height($(this).parent().next().height());
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pFbXd/1/)**

Or if you want to set the first box height equal to second box height then use:

```
$('.content-box:eq(0)').height($('.content-box:eq(1)').height());
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pFbXd/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

Another way..This may not be the best. But this works.

I give id for each content-box as  and

And use this jquery

```
    var cb1_height = $("#cb1").outerHeight();
    var cb2_height = $("#cb2").outerHeight();
    if(cb1_height>cb2_height)
    {
        $(".content-box").height(cb1_height);
    }else
    {
        $(".content-box").height(cb2_height);
    }
```